# System.ArgumentException (Parameter is not valid) in C#

Tags: c#, exception, bitmap

I have a code to convert several JPG files. Here is the code:

```
            Parallel.ForEach(strarrFileList, strJPGImagePath =>
            {
                Bitmap bmpDest = new Bitmap(1, 1);

                creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(strJPGImagePath);
                lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(strJPGImagePath);
                lastAccessTime = File.GetLastAccessTime(strJPGImagePath);

                try
                {
                    using (Bitmap bmpOrig = new Bitmap(strJPGImagePath))
                    {
                        intImageW = bmpOrig.Width;
                        intImageH = bmpOrig.Height;

                        if ((intImageW > intImageH) && (intImageW > intLongSide))
                        {
                            intImageH = (int)((double)intImageH / ((double)intImageW / (double)intLongSide));
                            intImageW = intLongSide;
                        }
                        else if ((intImageH > intImageW) && (intImageH > intLongSide))
                        {
                            intImageW = (int)((double)intImageW / ((double)intImageH / (double)intLongSide));
                            intImageH = intLongSide;
                        }
                        else if ((intImageH == intImageW) && (intImageW > intLongSide))
                        {
                            intImageH = intLongSide;
                            intImageW = intLongSide;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //something
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            bmpDest = new Bitmap(bmpOrig, new Size((Int32)intImageW, (Int32)intImageH));
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex1)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                bmpDest.Save(strJPGImagePath, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
                bmpDest.Dispose();

                File.SetCreationTime(strJPGImagePath, creationTime);
                File.SetLastWriteTime(strJPGImagePath, lastWriteTime);
                File.SetLastAccessTime(strJPGImagePath, lastAccessTime);
            });
```

It works perfectly for less than 50 JPG files, but when number of files increases it gives me exception at ex1 or ex2 randomly. The exception is:

**An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mCPanel.exe but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Parameter is not valid.**

When I change the target OS to X64, I don't get any exception. But I need to solve this on X86. I found several posts on stackoverflow, but not really an answer to this.

I appreciate any help.

EDIT: This is the updated code which still has the same issue:

```
            Parallel.ForEach(strarrFileList, strJPGImagePath =>
            {
                creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(strJPGImagePath);
                lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(strJPGImagePath);
                lastAccessTime = File.GetLastAccessTime(strJPGImagePath);

                Bitmap bmpOrig = new Bitmap(strJPGImagePath);
                intImageW = bmpOrig.Width;
                intImageH = bmpOrig.Height;

                if ((intImageW > intImageH) && (intImageW > intLongSide))
                {
                    intImageH = (int)((double)intImageH / ((double)intImageW / (double)intLongSide));
                    intImageW = intLongSide;
                }
                else if ((intImageH > intImageW) && (intImageH > intLongSide))
                {
                    intImageW = (int)((double)intImageW / ((double)intImageH / (double)intLongSide));
                    intImageH = intLongSide;
                }
                else if ((intImageH == intImageW) && (intImageW > intLongSide))
                {
                    intImageH = intLongSide;
                    intImageW = intLongSide;
                }
                else
                {
                    //do something
                }

                Bitmap bmpDest = new Bitmap(bmpOrig, new Size((Int32)intImageW, (Int32)intImageH));
                bmpOrig.Dispose();
                GC.SuppressFinalize(bmpOrig);

                bmpDest.Save(strJPGImagePath, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
                bmpDest.Dispose();
                GC.SuppressFinalize(bmpDest);

                File.SetCreationTime(strJPGImagePath, creationTime);
                File.SetLastWriteTime(strJPGImagePath, lastWriteTime);
                File.SetLastAccessTime(strJPGImagePath, lastAccessTime);
            });
```

Comment: Most likely a memory issue, pretty sure x86 processes will throw in debug once mem hits 1GB, its higher in x64, maybe batch processing would be a better solution as this may flake out a lot sooner with systems with less RAM

Comment: It definitely sounds like a memory issue. x86 has got its limitations and surely can't match the behavior/pattern of a x64 OS. I think, just for testing, you can add the following code after calling dispose
`GC.SuppressFinalize(bmpDest);`
It will release any unmanaged resources immediately used by the object, bmpDest.

Comment: @P.K. thank you. How about the one inside using? sometimes exceptions happens at ex1? should I remove "using" and instead use bmpOrig.Dispose(); and after that use GC.SuppressFinalize(bmpOrig); ?

Comment: @P.K. I updated the code (it is in the main post). It still does not work and shows the same exception. Any other solution?

Comment: @M0HS3N you might wanna give a try to the code `GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);` just after the dispose instead of `GC.SuppressFinalize(object);` This should not be treated as a perfect soln. Dispose only signal the releases of memory. This will happen only when GC has ran which is quite unpredictable. Till then even though you have called the dispose and the object does not exist, the memory can not be used by the compilers. GC.Collect forces the Garbage collector to run immediately after the dispose.

Comment: @P.K. thanks for your comment. It decreases the number of times I get the exception, but still it happens. Any other solution? Is this all because of tasks? Is there any other way to use kind of multi-threading without this issue?

Comment: @M0HS3N sorry 4 such a late reply. Like I said `GC.Collect` is not a perfect soln 'cause you can't completely rely on it. You might wanna try a diff approach. Instead of Parellel.ForEach use traditional foreach on a single new Task. Parellel.ForEach creates more than one thread for completion which may not be ideal in this case. Plz refer, [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/26/9641563.aspx).